# React project bundle ERROR Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, webpack, unexpected-token

I'm trying to build a React project from scratch, using webpack and not preconfigured create-react-app.

When I run `npx webpack --mode development`  , I get the ERROR:

> ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:4
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:4)You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
>
> | const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
>
> | root.render(
>
> \>     <Menu recipes={data}/>
>
> | );
>
> |

I installed the necessary dependencies to my project .

In `index.js`, there is simply root element defined and rendered:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import data from "./data/recipes.json";
import Menu from "./components/Menu";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <Menu recipes={data}/>
);
```

Also what I wrote in webpack/`config.js` :

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        "path": path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        "filename": "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}]
    },
    devtool: "source-map"
};
```

I figured the problem must be with the dependencies version conflict.

So I ran `npm install package-name@latest --save-dev` for every dependency.

However, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `test: ...` to `test: /\.js|\.jsx$/`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. I believe the issue is not a file extension, since the error occured in `./src/index.js`, which I included to bundle

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually changing the encoding of all js files to utf-8. Never knew this could be the case, since I never shifted it in the first place.